# Como convertir hora decimal a HH:MM en líneas especificas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame, con miles de lineas. Que vienen de un formulario y mucha gente coloco horas en números decimales, como presentado en el DataFrama abajo. Donde se supone que: `0.5 = 00:30`

```
   Hr_operacao  Hr_efetiva_oper 
0   03:18:00    02:00:00
1    0,5        02:30:00
2   02:00:00    01:00:00
3       3          2,4  
4   04:00:00       null
```

Necesito convertir todos los números decimales en el formato `HH:MM`. Si aplico una funcion, el se aplica para toda la columna y da error. Como puedo crear una función que solamente se aplique en los números decimales y no en los formatos que ya se encuentran correctamente?

Función que convierte decimales en HH:MM

```
def horas(numero):
 tiempo =numero 
 horas=int(tiempo)
 minutos=(tiempo*60) % 60
 return "%02d:%02d"%(horas,minutos)
```

Estuve googleando y pensé en aplicar una lógica similar al código abajo. Donde el `try` verifique el formato `HH:MM` caso de un error de valor. Aplique la función de conversión con el `except`, pero no sé muy bien como aplicarlo

```
try:
    # Codigo a ejecutar
    # Pero podria haber errores en este bloque
    
except <tipo de error>:
    # Haz esto para manejar la excepcion
    # El bloque except se ejecutara si el bloque try lanza un error
    
else:
    # Esto se ejecutara si el bloque try se ejecuta sin errores
   
finally:
    # Este bloque se ejecutara siempre
```

Pero no entiendo bien como aplicarla

Comment: Pregunta, los numeros decimales tienen el formato [cifras enteras].[cifras decimales] o lo mismo pero con coma? Además, asumo por sentido común que la columna es de tipo str, pero podrías aclararlo en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: @DanteS. Fui a verificar el `type` del DataFrame es el tipo `object` ambas columnas. Además, los números se encuentran en decimales efectivamente. Pero no sería un problema, creo, puedo convertirlos en formato `0.5`

Comment: Ya veo. Mi nueva pregunta entonces es, podrías decirme cual es el tipo de dato de las horas "normales" y de las decimales por favor?

Comment: Las horas normales se encuentran en formato `datetime64[ns]` y los decimales en `str`, además los `null` en `str`

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

La forma más sencilla que se me ocurre de adaptar la solución a lo que ya tienes es utilizar `regex` para identificar el formato de cada celda.

Utilizando los datos de tu pregunta en un archivo "sample.csv" (Agregué una fila más al final para mostrar un elemento vacío `NaN`):

```
  Hr_operacao Hr_efetiva_oper
0    03:18:00        02:00:00
1         0,5        02:30:00
2    02:00:00        01:00:00
3           3             2,4
4    04:00:00             NaN
5         NaN        03:05:10
```

Revisamos el formato de cada celda y lo comparamos con el siguiente `regex`:

```
re.match('^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)', numero)
```

**Nota:** Este `regex` revisa que el tiempo esté entre `00:00:00` y `23:59:59`, si desearas incluir horas más grandes, por ejemplo `30:30:30` tendrías que editar la primera parte `[01]\d|2[0-3]` que es donde se evaluan las horas. Lo mismo para minutos y segundos que revisan que sea un valor entre `00` y `59`.

Si la celda tiene un `string` con el formato correcto entonces devuelve el mismo valor, pero si no es así, entonces lo convierte al formato correcto (Esto considerando que siempre está en decimal (Por ejemplo, no consideré el caso de que tenga un `string` "media hora"). Si no tiene nada entonces devuelve `00:00:00`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def horas(numero):
    if pd.isna(numero):
        return '00:00:00'
    elif re.match('^((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$)', numero):
        return numero
    else:
        num = float(numero.replace(',', '.'))
        horas = int(num)
        minutos = (num*60) % 60
        segundos = (num*3600) % 60
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (horas, minutos, segundos)


df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
df['Hr_operacao'] = df['Hr_operacao'].apply(horas)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
  Hr_operacao Hr_efetiva_oper
0    03:18:00        02:00:00
1    00:30:00        02:30:00
2    02:00:00        01:00:00
3    03:00:00             2,4
4    04:00:00             NaN
5    00:00:00        03:05:10
```

**Nota:** Intenté que al leer el `csv` considerara las comas `,` como separador de decimales pero parece que no funcionó del todo así que adentro de la función hice la conversión de forma manual con un `replace`.

**Nota adicional:** La función la hice para procesar series (Es decir columna por columna) pero podrías modificarla para procesar todo el `dataframe` y analizar fila por fila, y de ese modo convertir todas las columnas que se necesite convertir con un solo `apply` en lugar de llamar `apply` para cada columna.

Comment: Lo siento no tengo más tiempo de probar por qué el `decimal = ','` no funcionó del todo al leer el `csv`.

Comment: Por que no usar la funcion strftime, del modulo datetime, que devuelve un ValueError cuando el tiempo no es valido.  O mejor, por que no intentar convertir en flotante todo y si la conversion falla dejarlo como está. O aun mejor, procesar solo las cadenas y devolver el valor original si no es una cadena.

Comment: Al intentar procesar celda por celda con el código que intenté reproducir el problema, todas son de tipo `string`. Tal vez un `try` y `except` podría funcionar de igual forma pero en lo personal no me gusta utilizarlos xD por eso opté por el `regex` aunque eso conllevaría utilizar una librería más (`import re`)

Comment: Tiene sentido, tiene sus peligros el try-except (aunque si los usas bien podes evitar buena parte). Pero para mi, es mejor utilizar una validacion que fue revisada por mucha gente por años que una regex creada recientemente por un usuario de Stack Overflow (perdon si ofendo, no es por desprestigiar tu esfuerzo)

Comment: Por cierto, podes usar el metodo fullmatch para ahorrarte aclarar en la regex el principio y final de la cadena.

Comment: @DanteS. Lo que sucede es que en lo personal siento que al usar try y except es como que me doy por vencido, como que me rindo y no pienso en los posibles escenarios y consecuencias, por eso prefiero no utilizarlos haha, una forma de retarme

Comment: Entiendo. Tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Creas una condición para convertir los datos de fechas en decimales a formato horario:

```py
def float2time(floatTime):
    if not ":" in floatTime:
        floatTime=floatTime.replace(",",".") # using dot as decimal symbol
        floatTime=str(datetime.timedelta(hours=float(floatTime)))
    return floatTime
```

Si no tiene `:` entonces convertir el número decimal a fecha.

Luego puedes convertir la columna entera a *datetime*.

```py
result=df["Hr_operacao"].map(float2time)
pd.to_datetime(result, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Salida:

```
0   2022-09-16 03:18:00
1   2022-09-16 00:30:00
2   2022-09-16 02:00:00
3   2022-09-16 03:00:00
4   2022-09-16 04:00:00
```